# Cannot find variable error?

Tags: java, currency

So I am trying to figure out why when I try to edit the boolean equals method so that it has this.dollars == o.dollars it gives me an error code on the second dollars variable in the code and says it cannot find the variable? I know I have a lot of other errors besides this one.

Also, for anyone that is willing to answer, what are the getMoney and setMoney methods there for? Why do I need that instead of just dollars and cents?

```
public class Money
{   
private int dollars;
private int cents;
private double money;

public Money (int dol) {
    this.dollars = dol;
    cents = 0;
    if (dol < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Must be greater than 0.");
    }
}

public Money (int dol, int cent) {
    dol = this.dollars;
    cent = this.cents;
    if (dol < 0 || cent < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Must be greater than 0.");
    }
}

public Money (Money other) {
    this.dollars = other.dollars;
    this.cents = other.cents;
    this.money = other.money;
}

public int getDollars () {
    return dollars;
}

public int getCents () {
    return cents;
}

public void setMoney (int dollars, int cents) {
    dollars = this.dollars;
    cents = this.cents;
    if (dollars < 0 || cents < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Must be greater than 0.");
    }
    if (cents > 100) {
        int c = cents/100;
        int m = dollars + c;
    }
}

public double getMoney () {
    return money;
}

public void add (int dollars) {
    if (dollars < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Must be greater than 0.");
    }
}

public void add (int dollars, int cents) {
    if (dollars < 0 || cents < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Must be greater than 0.");
    }
}

public void add (Money other) {
}

public boolean equals (Object o) {

}

public String toString () {
    String c = String.format("%.02d",cents);
    return "$" + dollars + "." + c;
}
```

}

Comment: I cannot find this.dollars == o.dollars in your pasted code, paste the correct code

Comment: Sorry, I had taken it out because it wasn't compiling when it was in there. It should be public boolean equals (Object o) {
return (this.dollars == o.dollars) && (this.cents =- o.cents);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the wrong way around

```
public Money (int dol, int cent) {
    dol = this.dollars;
    cent = this.cents;
    if (dol < 0 || cent < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Must be greater than 0.");
    }
}
```

try

```
public Money (int dol, int cent) {
    this.dollars = dol;
    this.cents = cent;
    if (dol < 0 || cent < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Must be greater than 0.");
    }
}
```

likewise for `public void setMoney (int dollars, int cents) {`

**Regarding** `equals`

In `equals` the `o` Object should be tested to see if it is a `Money` object using `instanceof` and if so it can then be cast as a Money Object

```
if( o instanceof Money) {
   return this.dollars == ((Money)o).dollars && this.cents == ((Money)o).cents;  // etc
}
```

Comment: I tried changing them around and it didn't make a difference; As for the instanceof, would it be something like this? public boolean equals (Object o) {
        if (o instanceof Money) {
            Money that = (Money) o;
            return this.dollars == that.dollars && this.cents == that.cents)
        }
        return false;
    }

Comment: Yep, that is almost right.  remove the `)` in `== that.cents) }`

Comment: It is still saying it cannot find the variable dollars!

Comment: I'm thinking it will give the same error for o.cents but it hits o.dollars first. I just can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: If you replaced your code and rebuilt it, there should be no code with `o.dollars` etc

Comment: Oh, I just used your code that you commented and it worked. thank you so much!!